# Editing h:dataTable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

The functionality I need is as follows:
I have a datatable with 4 columns(already works well, for the purpose of explanation I provided just one column "Price") and in the last column I have a "modify" icon. When I click on "modify" icon I would like inputText to pop-up where I can do my modifications for each column in the row.
From technical perspective I'm doing it:

In JSF:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{item.getItemList()}" var="c"
    styleClass="order-table"
    headerClass="order-table-header"
    rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header"> Price </f:facet>
        <h:inputText value="#{c.price}" size="5" rendered="#{c.editable}" />
        <h:outputText value="#{c.price}"  rendered="#{not c.editable}" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header"> Operation </f:facet>
        <h:form>
            <h:commandLink action="#{item.editAction(c)}">
                <h:graphicImage library="images"
                                name="modifyIcon.png"
                                width="20"
                                rendered="#{not c.editable}"/>
            </h:commandLink>
        </h:form>
        <h:form>
            <h:commandLink action="#{item.removeItem(c)}">
                <h:graphicImage value="resources/images/deleteIcon.png"  width="20" />
            </h:commandLink>
        </h:form>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

In bean:

```
public String editAction(Item item) {
    item.setEditable(true);
    return null;
}
```

and in Item class:

```
public boolean isEditable() {
    return this.editable;
}

public void setEditable(boolean editable) {
    this.editable = editable;
}
```

Then when I click on modifyIcon.png nothing happends. I would expect input fields from the other columns to show up, but they don't. Do you have any idea where I could made a mistake?

Comment: maybe it has something to do with scopes? The bean and the model class  are @ApplicationScoped.

Comment: Why do you use a separate `<h:form>` for each individual `<h:commandLink>`?

Comment: Application scope is definitely wrong for this purpose, but not the cause of this specific problem. To exclude one and other, is `editAction()` method actually invoked or not? If not, when/where exactly are you loading the data for the property behind `getItemList()`? Variable names in your code are by the way not consistent and therefore confusing. The name "item" references two entirely different things in your code.

Comment: Probably even request scope would be sufficient here. Regarding editAction(), it's invoked and changes the model as expected(setEditable() is set to true), but when I resume a program(break point) I enter isEditable() which already returns false. So something in between kills the flag I've just set.

Comment: @Tiny, right, one form is enough(I changed it, but the problem with editable flag is still there).

Answer (score 0):

since you don't show us where and how you load the list of items, we cannot give you one absolute answer. but here is a working example:

```
import java.io.Serializable;    
public class TestItem implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2725423502616632442L;
    private int id;
    private double price;
    private boolean editable;       
    public TestItem(int id, double price, boolean editable) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.price = price;
        this.editable = editable;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public boolean isEditable() {
        return editable;
    }
    public void setEditable(boolean editable) {
        this.editable = editable;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
@ManagedBean(name="testBean")
@SessionScoped 
public class Test implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2010307013874058143L;
    private List<TestItem> items;
    public Test(){

    }
    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        items = new ArrayList<TestItem>();
        items.add(new TestItem(0,20.99,false));
        items.add(new TestItem(1,30.90,false));
        items.add(new TestItem(2,23.00,false));
        items.add(new TestItem(3,15.50,false));
    }
    public final String setEditable(TestItem selectedItem){     
        selectedItem.setEditable(true);
        return null;// null or your view-id
    }
    public final String save(){     
        for(TestItem i: this.getItems()){
            System.out.println(i.getPrice());
            i.setEditable(false);
        }
        return null;// null or your view-id
    }
    public List<TestItem> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
    public void setItems(List<TestItem> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

xhtml:

```
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable id="DATA-TABLE" var="c" value="#{testBean.items}">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header"> Name </f:facet>
            <h:inputText value="#{c.price}" size="5" rendered="#{c.editable}" />
            <h:outputText value="#{c.price}" rendered="#{not c.editable}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header"> Operation </f:facet>
            <h:commandButton action="#{testBean.setEditable(c)}" value="EDIT"
                rendered="#{not c.editable}">
            </h:commandButton>
            <h:commandButton action="#{testBean.save}" value="SAVE"
                rendered="#{c.editable}">
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Comment: @Tiny, i tested his code and tried many things with and without ajax, ...etc. played with requestScoped Bean and so on, so while i tested i added prependId="false", ...etc., but no need for it in my example above. thanks!